# .NET Core CLR debugger VSDBG halts the application when attaching to a remote process in a Windows Docker container

Tags: .net, debugging, docker, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I have a .NET Core application running in a [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) Docker container that I want to attach Visual Studio Code to. When I do attach to the remote process, it seem the process freezes and if I disconnect the debugger, the container shuts down without any errors.

File *launch.json*:

```json
{
    "name": ".NET Core Remote Attach",
    "type": "coreclr",
    "request": "attach",
    "pipeTransport": {
        "pipeProgram": "powershell",
        "pipeArgs": ["docker exec -i --privileged amazing_johnson" ],
        "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "debuggerPath": "c:\\coreclr-debug\\vsdbg.exe"
    },
    "processId": "1736"
},
```

Results in the *Debug Output Console*:

```
Starting: "powershell" "docker exec -i --privileged amazing_johnson" "c:\coreclr-debug\vsdbg.exe --interpreter=vscode"
```

After attaching the debugger to the remote process, when I try to visit the site, it just hangs. Visual Studio Code lists the threads and displays some JSON in the terminal, but nothing happens. Disconnecting from it shuts down the container. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be related to this GitHub issue:

*[Visual Studio Code hangs on breakpoint when attached to a remote debugger on a Windows Docker container #31070](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31070)*